# Удаление сессии в PHP

Tags: php

Нужно после удаления профиля завершить сессию.

Удаление происходит в отдельном файле:

```
// Удаление себя пользователем
if(isset($_POST['deletebyuser'])){

...

    //очистка сессии
    unset ($_SESSION["login"]);
    $_SESSION['login'] = false;
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=../index.php">';
    die;
}
```

При переносе в index.php сессия сохраняется. Почему?

Возможно потому, что в шапке которая подключена к index.php прописано: session_start(); но я же её завершил в прошлом файле?
Как полностью выкинуть эту сессию?

Comment: вы уверены что прошлый файл запустил удаление сессии? Ведь там есть условие, которое может не выполняться. Как вы определили что прошлая сессия не уничтожилась?

Comment: Условие выполняется, этот код по удалению сессии точно читается. После перенаправления в другой файл index.php если вывести $_SESSION["login"] то выведется логин удалённого профиля

Comment: а вы в файле удаления сессию стартуете?

Comment: Я бы попробовал одновременно с удалением сессии чистить куку авторизации у юзера через setcookie(), там phpsessid или как-то так она называется, должно помочь